# Bash Script with a loop of 2 variables

Tags: bash, loops, gitlab

I'm having some hard time to work this one out. I need to feed GITLAP API with issues that are created based on a file that i have. Normally the output of the file is the following:

**Microsoft xxx xxxxx - Remote Code Execution xxxxxx- April 2018 xxxxx Updates
Red Hat Enterprise xxxx - java-1.8.0-xxxxx Multiple xxxxxxx- RHSA-xxxxxx**

So far so good, I already deal with this the following way:

```
while read in; do 
    curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/xxxxxx/issues?title="$in"; 
done < ~/input_file
```

The problem is now that i need to add a second variable to this because i need to introduce a description on each issue and now my input file change for the following:

Microsoft Malware Protection - Remote Code Execution Vulnerability - April 2018 Security Updates **40697**
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 - java-1.8.0-openjdk Multiple Vulnerabilities - RHSA-2018:1188 **40861**

I would like to construct something like this:

```
while read in; 
    curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxx/issues?title=$in&description=https://myspecialink.com/portal/notifications/show/$id"; 
done < ~/input_file
```

for example:

- `$in`: must be everything except the bold number that i signalize above.
- `$id`: must be only the numbers in bold above.

Can someone help me on point me the best way of achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) operators to split the input.

```
while read in; do
    id=${in##* }  # Remove everything up to last space
    in=${in% *}   # Remove everything from last space
    curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxx/issues?title=$in&description=https://myspecialink.com/portal/notifications/show/$id"; 
done
```

Comment: Thank-you i add to tweak it a little bit because my input file is not like the example i gave here but it is really a nice way of dealing with this. Thank-you for your help.